# Can I specify a header row when sorting in a script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that I'd like to sort by multiple columns many times as I work on the document. This is a multi-step process using the GUI, and seemed far too time-consuming. I have to check the box for a header row, set up the first sorting parameter, and then add another one. Phew! It gets old quick.

Sorting the sheet was no problem, but the header row was also sorted! I don't find any way to specify that I have a header row as a parameter to the sort() function, nor do I see any way to globally define a header row that will be automatically noticed by sort().

In lieu of that, I saved the header row, deleted the first row, sorted the sheet, inserted a new row at the very top, re-created the header row, and formatted the header row. Wow! It didn't take that long to write and it works well, but it's awfully complicated!

From the user perspective, the header row briefly disappears before popping back up. It's not too bad, but it's plainly obvious something is going on.

So finally I get around to my question: Have I overlooked the ability to acknowledge the presence of a header row when I'm sorting? Or does sorting a sheet with a header row present in a script also sort the header row, with no recourse?

If my method, or one like it, is required to avoid including the header row in the sort process, is there somewhere that I can notify the Google Apps team so they can consider adding this feature? Since specifying the existence of a header row exists in the GUI with a simple checkbox, I hope it's present or can be added when sorting within a script.

**EDIT**

My original code (with documentation/comments removed):

```
sheet.deleteRow(1);

rows.sort([<1st col>, <2nd col>]);

sheet.insertRowsBefore(1, 1);
for (var j = 0; j <= (numCols - 1); j++) {
  sheet.getRange(1, (j + 1)).setValue(firstRow[j]);
}

sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numCols).setFontWeight("bold");
sheet.getRange(1, 1, 2, numCols).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
```

What I've tried in place of the above code thanks for Thomas' suggestion:

```
sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
sheet.sort(<2nd col>);
sheet.sort(<1st col>);
sheet.setFrozenRows(0);
```

Unfortunately, this just sorts by column, not by row. Replacing the 2 `sheet.sort();` calls with the `rows.short();` line in the first code block doesn't work. Trying this results in the initial problem I reported in my comment where the header row is sorted along with the other data, even though the first row is frozen before sorting.

Also, unless another line of code is added below this I get a perpetual "Working..." notification at the top of the spreadsheet. It doesn't seem to affect anything, however.

In all cases, `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`, `var rows = sheet.getDataRange();`, and `firstRow` is an array of the header row data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> In all cases, var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();, var rows =
>   sheet.getDataRange();, and firstRow is an array of the header row
>   data.

Rather than using getDataRange(), you can just get the range you want to sort (that is, exclude the header row):

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rows = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
```

---

*This next part is just an answer/observation to a "secondary" question:*

> After the script is finished, the header row was sorted along with all
>   the other rows although the first row is frozen.

I think this is a bit of a limitation in GAS where some of these "spreadsheet tool" methods don't play nice with one another - [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=918&q=hide%20columns&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner) is not the same as yours but I think it's (kind of) related.

So with the "frozen header" workaround, I'd be interested to see if `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` inserted just after `sheet.setFrozenRows(1);` makes it work.

Comment: SpreadsheetApp.flush() is indeed an interesting idea ;-) I guess your suggestion leads to think about doing the sort on the array rather than in the sheet itself... It would probably be more efficient don't you think ?

Comment: Oh definitely Serge, I should have made it clear that the first part of my answer is my attempt at a "proper" answer, and the second part is an answer to a secondary question.

Comment: Duh! Just exclude the first row from the rows I'm sorting. It works and is obviously much, much simpler to understand and maintain. It seems to run slowly, but I suspect this is a function of running the sort method (setting up the sorting manually takes just as long). Thank you! I'm marking this as an answer. By the way, adding `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` doesn't help. But thanks for the great suggestion!

Comment: Thought I'd add this idea: `function getDataRangeWithoutHeaders(sheet){ return sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn()); }`

Answer (score 4):

You want to do this:

- Create a spreadsheet
- Put in some random Data
- Freeze the first row, http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=54813

and then call this script:

```
function myFunction() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().sort(1);
}
```

And there you go :)

With kind regards,

Thomas van Latum

Comment: Thank you! I added `sheet.setFrozenRows(1);` before `rows.sort([<first col>, <2nd col>]);`, but it didn't work. After the script is finished, the header row was sorted along with all the other rows although the first row is frozen. Using the Undo command I find that the header row is frozen before sorting, but it's sorted with all the other rows anyway. So ultimately the first row in the sorted data is frozen. If I comment out the line that sorts, at the script end the header row is properly frozen. What might I be doing that prevents the frozen row from staying put as the first row?

Comment: If I follow your instructions to freeze the first row as you instructed, that's a manual operation. I can't accept that as a solution. The point of scripts is to automate tasks and remove manual intervention. Also `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().sort(1);` will sort the entire sheet by column, which doesn't work in my case because I have multiple columns in each row of data and I need to sort the entire row (but I wasn't incredibly clear about that!).

Comment: This works fine using `sheet.setFrozenRows(1);` to freeze the first row. No manual intervention required.

Comment: This was not added back in 2012. Please create a new answer and I'll up vote it.