# Delete multiple columns, then sort by price in Google Sheets (Script Editor)

Tags: javascript, sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently run a simple daily script to sort my products by price. This is done with freezing the first row (headers).

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// Sorts the sheet by the column I - the ninth across - , in ascending order 
sheet.sort(9);
}
```

I need to import some data now with a Python script which has issues dealing with frozen rows. So I need to run a cleanup script when it has finished, within my Google Sheet.

*How can I delete columns D, F, H and then sort by price in column I (without having to freeze the top row) all with a single Google Script?*

**Part 1**https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet

```
sheet.deleteColumn(4,6,8);
```

**Part 2** - possible header ignore [Google Apps Script: Can I specify a header row when sorting in a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687541/google-apps-script-can-i-specify-a-header-row-when-sorting-in-a-script)

```
sheet.getRange(2, 1, height-1, width+1).sort(width+1);
```

Comment: Instead of cleaning it up afterwards you could run a google script that writes the data needed by your python script into another sheet to make it easier to import. But deleting and sorting columns can be done with `Range.moveTo` and `Range.sort`. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

Comment: Great idea, which I might need to go with. Got my function now - but would need to clear the sheet and then import another Google sheet daily. Any ideas on what would be needed to pop that in a function?    ```//Clear sheet, ready for import
    clear();

    // Import content from Google Sheet #
    ??```

Comment: You mean one of your sheets is dedicated to importing data and each day you want to import another sheets data into it? You can use `Sheet.clear()` and `Range.copyTo()` for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

//Clear sheet, ready for import
clear();

// Import content from Google Sheet
??

// Delete unused columns
sheet.deleteColumn(4);
sheet.deleteColumn(5);
sheet.deleteColumn(6);

// Freeze first row
sheet.setFrozenRows(1);

// Sort by price
sheet.sort(4);

// Unfreeze first row
sheet.setFrozenRows(0);
}
```